# SASS Won't Compile @import Google Font CDN

Tags: css, compiler-errors, sass, compass

I've had this issue lately on other developers SASS projects where the Google CDN import won't compile -- See screenshots, saves fine when commented out.

I read a few articles on this issue and it was suggested to do this command:

`gem install compass`

I don't use compass, I use a SASS plugin for Coda. Guessing the previous developer used Compass to compile? Figured this might help the compiling issue.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Sass import code should look like this:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,700italic,400,300,700);
```

You are importing from an URL, but your code is written as if you were importing a local file—that is why the error message says it can't be found.

Here's a little tutorial on [how to use Google fonts with Sass](http://www.developerdrive.com/2014/05/how-to-easily-use-google-fonts-with-sass/).

Comment: Thanks! Weird... Works in the other devs environment. Your suggestion worked.

Comment: My problem is that I have single quote inside parenthesis. Remove it as in your answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

### We can import separate Sass file in .scss

For example we have two file one in local directory of project and other one in on CDN server/online server (such as google fonts).

> local file: css/nameofstylsheet.scss

&

> Online Server: http://fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,700italic,400,300,700);

### we used them as:

```
@import "css/nameofstylsheet.scss";

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Open+Sans:300italic,700italic,400,300,700);
```

Comment: You're missing a questionmark between `css` and `family`.

Answer (score 0):

The import code should look like this:

```
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Spartan&display=swap');
```

Or you can link the font file directly in your html with the link tag as:

```html
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Spartan&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```