# SASS not compiling external Google Font with @import

Tags: css, sass, gulp-sass, google-font-api

I'm using the following line in scss:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,700);
```

Which gets compiled to css without errors to... exactly the same:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,700);
```

But it should get compiled to:

```
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;

etc...
```

I'm using [gulp sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass) to compile my scss, which is based on `libsass`. It says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26350079/943337) that my syntax is correct. Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in fact expected behaviour. Quoting the [Sass docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import):

> @import takes a filename to import. By default, it looks for a Sass
>   file to import directly, but there are a few circumstances under which
>   it will compile to a CSS @import rule:
>
> - If the file’s extension is .css.
> - If the filename begins with http://.
> - If the filename is a url().
> - If the @import has any media queries.

In other words: Sass does not integrate the css from google fonts directly into your css file. Instead, at runtime, the css import directive will resolve the link. Google responds differently depending on your browser by the way.

Comment: Okay! I noticed for example for Android @import in the css doesn't work. Does that mean I'm stuck with loading the google font css separately?

Comment: It's probably easiest to use the link directive: `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,700" rel="stylesheet">`. It's also better for performance, as @import can prevent stylesheets from being downloaded concurrently.

You could open the google font link in your browser, and copy the css declarations into your own stylesheet, but as I mentioned, google serves a slightly different response depending on the browser, so I wouldn't advise this. So yes, I would say you're stuck with loading the google font css separately.

Comment: Clear! Thanks. Marked as answered.